# Example for Ketai Library Bluetooth Listener Example

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, processing, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to send data from Arduino (UNO) to Android (Nexus 7) (2012) and I'm using Processing for Android and Ketai library. I need some example code for using the KBluetoothListener class to receive the data. I'm a novice for both Arduino and Android programming. Help Needed.

Comment: If you can get a copy of "Rapid Android Development", it was written by Daniel Sauter, one of the co-authors of the Ketai library. It's a really good book, and has lots of source code in it... http://pragprog.com/book/dsproc/rapid-android-development

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar.  Perhaps you may find what I am working on useful: https://github.com/Plan99/BrainGoggles.  In this code, I send data from the bluetooth on the Arduino to the Android using SoftwareSerial.

Also, I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215211/bluetooth-communication-between-android-and-arduino-using-processing/19219203#comment28921121_19219203) on this site, so you could take a look at that.