# Bluetooth communication between Android and Arduino using Processing

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, processing, serial-communication

I am trying to make two-way bluetooth communication between Android and Arduino using Processing for Android.  I have success transferring data from the Android to the Arduino with serial.begin(9600).  And I have success transferring data from the Arduino to the Android by using SoftwareSerial in the Arduino program and bluetooth.begin(9600) in place of serial.begin(9600).

However, when trying to transfer data from the Android to the Arduino using bluetooth.x commands, it does not work.  Here is the Arduino code:

```
  if (bluetooth.available()) // Wait until a character is received
  {
    char val = (char)bluetooth.read();
    //Serial.println(val);

    switch(val) // Perform an action depending on the command
    {
      case 'w'://turn the light on when a 'w' is received
      on();
      break;

      case 'q'://turn the light off when a 'q' is received
      off();
      break;

      //default://otherwise remain in the previous state
      //idle();
      break;
    }
  }
```

The on() and off() functions switch on and off an LED on the Arduino.  As mentioned, this works when I'm using serial.x commands and not bluetooth.x commands.  Also, I am using Ketai for Processing for Android.  I am using Processing 2.0.1, Arduino 1.0.5, Android 2.3.6.

Here is the relevant beginning code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(0,1);  //TX 0, RX 1
```

Comment: "Arduino 2.0.5"? Are you some kind of time traveler? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more code would be greatly appreciated...

Have you included something like that?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int bluetoothTx = 2;
int bluetoothRx = 3;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
```

**EDIT:**

That's similar to what I use.
You first upload the code without the bluetooth wired and then wire the bluetooth. Then you can simply use `Serial.doSomething()` because you are using the same pins, you don't need `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`. But you need to make sure that the baudrate is the same.

You can try this code to make sure it works fine:

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600); // or wathever your bluetooth module baudrate is

}

void loop(){

    Serial.println("Hello World!"); // to make sure it works.
    delay(500);

}
```

You should also make sure you you Arduino is connected to the computer via bluetooth.

Comment: That is similar to what I used.  Please see above code.  I can provide more code (or all of it), but I didn't want to spam the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can provide more code or link to something readable.
As for your edit, Software serial is used to mimic the Serial port RX and TX on other ports because your usb uses pins 0 and 1 for serial communication with your computer.
What bluetooth module do you use? How is it wired?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I just figured out how to upload to [GitHub](https://github.com/Plan99/BrainGoggles/tree/master).  The bluetooth is DFRobot's "V3" and the Arduino is a Nano (UNO compatible).  Pins 0 and 1 are linked to the bluetooth, so I actually have to take out the bluetooth to upload to the Arduino.

Comment: I just fixed the problem by using by using softwareserial and different pins for the bluetooth (pins 4 and 2 for TX and RX).  This solved the problem at hand and removed the need to unplug the bluetooth module during uploads.  On the downside, I used up my last two digital ports on the Arduino.

Comment: Yep, that's a great solution too! I'm doing the same for my project and it works great. There's one thing I'd like to know how to do it how to upload sketches through bt. That remains to be found...